# Model fit failed in Caret GBM and all the RMSE metric values are missing:

Tags: r, r-caret, gbm

I have encountered the errors as indicated in the title and looked through the solutions for similar problems posted online by checking for null values, changing the predictor variables to numeric as well as pre-process the variables with center and scale but to no avail.

I am able to run the model using the same data in Caret for RF as well as with a range of tunegrid options for each GBM parameter but not when I specify the optimal value for each GBM parameter.

My train data comprises  a regression target variable (Gross.Salary0) and my predictor variables are either factor(binary) or numeric. There are no missing values in my data. A subset of data without the full number of variables is as follows:

```
structure(list(Gross.Salary0 = c(3043.7, 4170, 3148.4, 3678.4, 3586.4,
3126.4), Gender.MALE. = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label =  
c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), Certificate...HQA.MASTER.S.DEGREE....Outflow.Date..2. 
= c(0L, 1875929344L, 0L, 1706185636L, 0L, 0L), Certificate...HQA.HONS.I.
= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = 
"factor"), Year.of.Inflow... = c(2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L), Year.of.Inflow..2. = c(4036081L, 4036081L, 4036081L, 4036081L,
4036081L, 4036081L), Age...5....Agency.10. = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
Inflow.Date..2....Agency.10. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = 
c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

To obtain the optimal tuning parameters for Caret GBM in R, I manage to run the following code:

```
fit_control2 <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, search="grid")

grid <- expand.grid(n.trees=c(10,20,50,100,500,1000),shrinkage=c(0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5),n.minobsinnode = c(3,5,10),interaction.depth=c(1,5,10))

gbm_model2 <-train(Gross.Salary0 ~ ., data=train, method='gbm',trControl=fit_control2, tuneGrid=grid)

gbm_model2
```

The results produce the lowest RMSE when n.trees = 1000, interaction.depth = 1, shrinkage = 0.05 and n.minobsinnode = 3.

I run the final GBM model using the optimal tuning parameters but return with a model fit error and all missing RMSE values.

```
fit_control3 <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, search="grid")

tunegrid <- expand.grid(n.trees=1000, interaction.depth = 1, shrinkage = 0.05, n.minobsinnode = 3)

gbm_model3 <- train(Gross.Salary0 ~ ., data=train, method="gbm", tunegrid =tunegrid, trControl=fit_control3)
```

Other than the missing RMSE values, there's 50 or more warnings with a sample as follows:

```
50: model fit failed for Fold07.Rep2: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=2, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=150 Error in (function (x, y, offset = NULL, misc = NULL, distribution = "bernoulli",  : 
unused argument (tunegrid = list(1000, 1, 0.05, 3))
```

Though my target variable is numeric (regression), I notice that the distribution indicated in the warning shows bernoulli, I've thus specified the distribution in my model to be gaussian but R still returns the same error.

Appreciate your help please, thanks.

Comment: could you reproduce the problem with an inbuilt data set. Your sample data is too small for the example to run.

Comment: Hi @missuse, I've uploaded my train dataset in GitHub https://github.com/christine83/Project1.git Thanks.

Comment: I have this problem too, but I think it's just not enough training data, and the gbm algorithm isn't built to handle this.